# Blackberry 10 list shared/camera folder content

Tags: blackberry-10, camera-roll

I am working on content transfer application. I have to transfer all media present in shared/camera folder in Blackberry 10 device to my Android device.

How can I get path of all media present in shared/camera folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [answer to your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003744/blackberry-10-scan-gallery) (don't start 2 threads on the same subject next time) and just pass `/accounts/1000/shared/camera` to the `findMediaFiles` method.

Comment: Thanks @Roger Leblanc. Sorry! next time I'll take care of it  (don't start 2 threads on the same subject next time).